# Java regular expression finding substring

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a program to convert Roman numerals into integers. The method I'm doing is looking for a sub-string which would signify subtractions (`IX`, `CM`, `XC`) and adding the respective amount to the tally. For example if `CM` is in the string `MMMMCMXCIX` then set the hundreds column to `9`.

I'm trying to do it with

```
    if(romanNum.matches("CM")){
        hundreds = 9;
        romanNum.replaceAll("CM", "");
    }
```

but it never enters the if statement. Using [these](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) [two](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/) regular expression checkers with the string `MMMMCMXCIX` and the regular expression solely as `CM` they both highlight a match yet my code suggests otherwise. Why is this?

Comment: `Matcher.matches()` checks if **all of the input** matches the pattern, in other words, it only matches in if the input is exactly `CM` and not if it is `MMMMCMXCIX`. Use other methods instead, such as [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--).

Comment: There are several issues with the code. 1) Use `contains` to check if a string contains a substring, 2) assign replaced values to a variable, 3) replacing literal substrings should be done with `String#replace`, not `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 0):

`String#matches` matches the whole `String` against your substring, which is why your condition never triggers unless your `String` value only consists in `"CM"`.

Either:

1. use `String#contains` (no regular expressions):

   e.g. `if(romanNum.contains("CM"))`
2. or, use a `Matcher` against a `Pattern` explicitly:

   e.g. `if (Pattern.compile("CM").matcher(romanNum).find())`

   Note that this doesn't make sense as is (prefer solution 1), unless you have an actual pattern.

Finally, you probably want to use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` if you're only replacing literals.